# Stream video from ffmpeg in java servlet

Tags: java, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming

Is it possible to start `ffmpeg` as external Process when the `doGet()` method of a servlet is called, and stream the stdout of ffmpeg to the response?

The `ffmpeg`-process should also be stopped once the request ends.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortulately I did not solve it yet.